# Where can I download older versions of Blender?

Tags: installation, versions

I was trying to re-download the original Blender 2.8, however it goes directly to the 2.81 download page instead.

How can I access downloads for previous versions of Blender and installers for older releases?

Comment: https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.80/

Comment: Every previous versions: https://download.blender.org/release/

Comment: Thank you @FFeller

Comment: @FFeller post an answer and  let me upvote you  :)

Comment: I downvoted this question because it shows extreme lack of effort and any research. The link to previous versions is on the same page.

Answer (score 5):

Accordoing to the blender.org fortunately "Your old files are safe, every Blender release is available for download. Forever." Just go to the download site and look for previous versions at the bottom of the page.

2.79:
https://www.blender.org/download/previous-versions/

2.80:
https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.80/

Every build:
https://download.blender.org/release/

Answer (score 0):

2.69: https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.69/

I had to install missing libraries in order for it to work:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libidn11:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libsdl1.2debian:i386
```

Note that you don't need `i386` if you're working on 64-bit machine (it's only needed for 32-bit)